How to calculate the time constant for an attenuation of specific frequencies in a Lock-in Amp?
I am new to the signal processing field, so I am studying what I can and trying to figure stuff out, but I have found one piece of information I really cannot find mentioned anywhere, yet seems very important.
How are the following time constants derived?
Reading the manual of a SR830 lock-in amp, page 3-11 says this:

Consider
an example where the reference is at 1 kHz and a
large noise signal is at 1.05 kHz. The PSD noise
outputs are at 50 Hz (difference) and 2.05 kHz
(sum). Clearly the 50 Hz component is the more
difficult to low pass filter. If the noise signal is
80 dB above the full scale signal and we would
like to measure the signal to 1% (-40 dB), then the
50 Hz component needs to be reduced by 120 dB.
To do this in two stages would require a time constant of at least 3 seconds. To accomplish the
same attenuation in four stages only requires
100 ms of time constant. In the second case, the
output will respond 30 times faster and the experiment will take less time.

Then it goes on explaining the synchronous filters:

At
low frequencies, the time constant required to
attenuate the 2F component can be quite long. For
example, at 1 Hz, the 2F output is at 2 Hz and to
attenuate the 2 Hz by 60 dB in two stages requires
a time constant of 3 seconds.

I could not find any calculation or formula that explain these results, so I would like to know how these are done.

Someone answered but now their reply has been removed? What happened?
